# How to stop bounce in jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I want to stop bounce my images with class 'lang' when I hovering my image are bounce again and again, but when I use `event.preventDefault()` it isn't stop and similar with `stop()` method. My code is simple.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lang').hover(function(){
   $(this).effect('bounce',1000);
  });
});
```

I used lines like

`event.preventDefault()` before animate line

`stop()` before effect method

`event.preventDefault()` after animate line

etc...

BUT

I used this

`.filter(":not(:animated)")`

And it works, but my friend - which is front-end dev - said that 'not' is not supported by web browsers.

So can I use something like `preventDefault()` or `stop()` to stop this effect?

Comment: To clarify my earlier statement (deleted as unproductive): When you use jquery selectors (the bit *inside* the `filter()`), you are not using any browser features, you are using a component of jquery called *sizzle* (see [here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15786014/2181514)).

Comment: `.preventDefault` relates to the *hover* event and has no bearing on animations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the currently-running animation. I think you should also use `.stop()` on `mouseleave` event.

```js
$('.lang').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true, true).effect("bounce", 1000);
},function() {
  $(this).stop(true, true);
});
```

```css
div.lang {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class='lang'></div>
```

Comment: I used your code, but I have problem with my image like this http://i67.tinypic.com/qn4klf.png

When I hover my image it goes to up. I checked on Safari and Chrome.

Comment: @falauthy, Can you update the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgu6cL2g/) with your exact problem so that we can repro

Comment: On this Fiddle You can see when you hovering box is going up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using v1.9 or above of jquery, you can use the (relatively) new

[`.finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/)

To re-iterate the docs linked above:

> When .finish() is called on an element, the currently-running animation and all queued animations (if any) immediately stop and their CSS properties set to their target values. All queued animations are removed.
>
> The .finish() method is similar to .stop(true, true) in that it clears the queue and the current animation jumps to its end value. It differs, however, in that .finish() also causes the CSS property of all queued animations to jump to their end values, as well.

---

So you would use this thus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lang').hover(function(){
   $(this).finish().effect('bounce',1000);
  });
});
```

Otherwise, if <1.9, use `.stop(true, true)` as per other answer.

Comment: I have problem with finish() method. When I hovering image, then text below this image is applied on image.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this.effect("bounce", { times:4 }, 300);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: sure @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 i will do it